# Instruct to execute an unit after completing another unit successfully

Tags: systemd, coreos, dcos, systemctl

Friends.

I use cloud-config to install and configure DCOS cluster.

Normally "agentinstall.service" service takes 5 minutes to complete.

Is it possible to instruct to systemd to execute "agentconfigure.service" ONLY AFTER "agentinstall.service" **completed**?

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
    - name: "agentinstall.service"
      command: "start"
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=agent_setup
        After=network.target

        [Service]
        Type=simple
        User=root
        WorkingDirectory=/tmp
        ExecStartPre=/bin/curl -o /tmp/dcos_install.sh  http://bootstapnode-0.dev.myztro.internal:9090/dcos_install.sh
        ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 755 dcos_install.sh
        ExecStart=/bin/bash dcos_install.sh slave

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
    - name: "agentconfigure.service"
      command: "start"
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=agent_config
        After=agentinstall.service

        [Service]
        Type=simple
        User=root
        WorkingDirectory=/opt/mesosphere/etc/
        ExecStartPre=/bin/echo "MESOS_ATTRIBUTES=cluster:uploader" >> /opt/mesosphere/etc/mesos-slave-common
        ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/latest
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart dcos-mesos-slave

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about system configuration and installation, not programming. Such a question is best for unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This is very much possible with systemd using `After/Before` keywords.
you can use something like below
In `agentconfigure.service`, provide below instruction

```
After=agentinstall.service
```

Usually `After` ensures that the dependent service is launched after launch of given service.

Since you mentioned that `agentinstall.service` takes 5 minutes to complete, so you have to add Type=notify in `agentinstall.service`, and from your application do a `sd_notify()` when your processing is done. 
Based on this systemd shall start next service i.e `agentconfigure.service`

Read more about same [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)
Read about sd_notify() [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html)